# IF Statement In View - Not Appearing

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-2

Okay, I'm trying to verify a subscription from a database (which appears to work fine, as I've used this model elsewhere). However, I'm trying to take the returned $data and use it as an IF Statement in my view...but the DIV I'm trying to "if" is not showing up. Nor do any errors appear. If I remove the IF around the DIV in the view, the content will appear...what am I doing wrong?

Here's the code in my controller:

```
// Check subscription and display appropriate content if "freebie" package 
$subscribe_result = $this -> subscribe_model -> upgrade_message($this->session->userdata('user_id')); // session sends user id to model
$data['subscription'] = $subscribe_result;
```

Model:

```
// Checks to see what package user has subscribed to
public function upgrade_message($id) //$id is session id pulled from controller
{
    $this -> db -> select('subscription'); // select the subscription column
    $this -> db -> where('id', $id); //find id in table that matches session id
    $query = $this -> db -> get("subscriptions"); // connect to this database

    return $query->result_array(); //returns the result of the above
}
```

and finally, my IF statement in the view I'm trying to output:

```
<? if($subscription == 'Freebie') : ?>
    <div>some "freebie" content</div>
<? endif ?>
```

Comment: If you do <? var_dump($subscription) ?> inside your view - you'll see what the variable contains. I bet you it is not "Freebie".

Comment: `$query->result_array();` returns an array and you are checking `Freebie`, this is the problem.

Comment: Here's the var dump: `array(1) { [0]=> array(1) { ["subscription"]=> string(7) "Freebie" } }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
if($subscription[0]['subscription'] == 'Freebie')
```

instead of

```
if($subscription == 'Freebie')
```

More about [Generating Query Results](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/results.html).

Comment: Works!! I SWEAR I had this the first time around - AGH!. Been 13 hours of coding today, maybe it's time to take a nap. lol :) Cheers Sheikh!

Comment: You might want to check that `$subscription` has a value first before calling `$subscription[0]` otherwise that will result in an error if there isn't a value... ;)